# SQL Table and Stored Procedure Creation of Total Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a table in SQL and am trying to retrieve a ROW that returns the Total of all rows in a the value column and names the description value 'Total'.  Is this done in the stored procedure?

EX: Table1

```
Column1 Column2 Desc   ValueColumn
1       6/30/14  One      11.1
2       6/30/14  Two      10.2
3       6/30/14   Three    9.0
```

I want the table to end looking like the following:
Table1

```
Column1 Column2 Desc  ValueColumn 
1       6/30/14  One       11.1        
2       6/30/14  Two       10.2        
3       6/30/14  Three      9.0        
4       6/30/14  Total     30.3
```

Can you please help with how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: which RDBMS ? sql server? my sql? oracle?

Comment: Do you actually want the row added to the table, or just the added row output from the query / stored procedure?

Comment: is the column2 field for all rows the same? if not, which value should be chosen for the "total" row?

Comment: do you want the contents of the table to change or simply what you are outputting to change? because you can have a sum when you query your table and not need to add a row that persists in the database

Comment: I'm trying to create a query that will add an additional ROW in the database that is the total.

Below is what I'm starting with:

PerfAttribAlphaID  ProductID   AsOfDate    AlphaSourceDesc   PerfAttribValue
1               1        2014-06-30 Currency 0.00000000
2               1        2014-06-30 Macro         50.00000000
3               1        2014-06-30 Quantitative 10.00000000
4               1        2014-06-30 Credit         90.00000000

Comment: Below is what I'm trying to end with:
PerfAttribAlphaID  ProductID   AsOfDate    AlphaSourceDesc   PerfAttribValue
1               1        2014-06-30 Currency 0.00000000
2               1        2014-06-30 Macro         50.00000000
3               1        2014-06-30 Quantitative 10.00000000
4               1        2014-06-30 Credit         90.00000000

Where PerfAttribAlphaID is a primary key (bigint) and increments by one for each row in the table, ProductID and AsOfDate are input parameters, AlphaSourceDesc is Total and PerfAttribValue is the sum of all previous rows in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an sql statement that does what you ask:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Desc, ValueColumn
FROM
(
   SELECT 1 as rolluporder, Column1, Column2, Desc, ValueColumn
   FROM TABLE
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2 as rolluporder, null as Column1, null as Column2, 
         'Total' AS Desc, SUM(ValueColumn) as ValueColumn 
   FROM TABLE
) T
ORDER BY rolluporder, Column1
```

This looks a little different but I expect it is what you really want:

```
Column1 Column2  Desc      ValueColumn 
1       6/30/14  One       11.1        
2       6/30/14  Two       10.2        
3       6/30/14  Three      9.0        
null    null     Total     30.3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @IDC AS INT 
SET @IDC = (
SELECT TOP 1 Column1 
FROM [yourtable]
ORDER BY 1 DESC 
)

SELECT *
FROM [yourtable]

UNION ALL 

SELECT @IDC, Column2, 'Total', SUM(ValueColumn)
FROM [yourtable]
GROUP BY Column2
```